# How can I get the subnet mask of another subnet in the same network,given that I have one of it's host IP address?

Tags: networking

Ex: My Target IP address is 10.7.19.119

And My IP address is 10.7.1.166
 and Subnet mask is 255.255.192.0

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not possible. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101520/get-subnet-mask-and-gateway-from-ip-address

Comment: The terms "network" and "subnet" are synonymous in modern networking. Every network is a subnet of another network. Back, when we had network classes in the (literally) last century, a subnet was derived from a default class network. Network classes were killed in 1993, by RFCs 1518 and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing).

Answer (score 0):

You can not simply calculate a subnet mask from just an IP address.
But you can try to get that info from your router/dhcp server.

I would try to assign your pc an IP address next to `10.7.19.119` for example: `10.7.19.120`.
Afterwards check your subnet mask with `ipconfig` excecuted in a command shell (cmd).